# Aligning bootstrap navbar to the bottom center of the screen - landing page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am using a bootstrap template, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get my navbar text to get to the bottom-center of the screen. I have tried editing the bootstrap css for .navbar, .navbar-right, etc with vertical-align: bottom. It [stays at the top no matter what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9bhj.png).

Here is a link to the bootstrap template http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/landing-page/

And here is the code:

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> -->
                <img src="img/RyanIsGreat.png" width=200px height=100px>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <!--Here is what I am trying to bottom-center align
                         The about, services, and contacts all appear 
                          on the right, as is shown in the image-->
                    <li>
                        
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `navbar-fixed-bottom` class..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
        ...
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/RBR3Hsg5bH

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this doesn't solve the problem. I want the bar to be at the top, but the text of the "About, services, contacts" to be at the bottom of the container. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: nice to know about, though.